# Google sheets formulas for checking max and then writting name of person in a different cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

so I have been working on automating this table for the most performing person of the week on google sheets.
[image: Weekly performance table]

now on the column O i have top candidate, I want to run an if statement that would check through the values of each person. for example, for day 1 it would check from K3 to N3 once it gets the value, it should post the name of the candidate. That means for week 1, day 1, it would check and see that charles has the top performance and post "Charles" on the top candidate cell of the same row.

so far i know how to know ts easy getting the number between the cells which has the biggest value =max(K3:N3) but then combining it with an if statement that would know the cell on top... that got me worked up and still not found an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula should work:

`=INDEX($K$2:N,1,MATCH(MAX($K3:$N3),$K3:$N3,0))`

MATCH will find a specific column that has the max value of K3:N3, then INDEX will reference the value of the top column.

Sample Sheet:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, it works. God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(
 IF(IF(K3:N="", "x", K3:N)=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(K3:N), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(LEN(J3:J), 
 "max(Col"&ROW(A3:A)-ROW(A3)+1&")", ))&"")), 
 "select Col2"), K2:N2, ))),,9^9))))
```

[image]